# How to enable checkbox on scroll down?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, scroll

I am trying to make a check box enabled once a user has scrolled to the bottom of a scrollable div.

Its for terms and conditions and I have got some code from similar questions on here but cant seem to get it to work.

I have some jQuery at the top of my file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#terms').scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height()) {
        $('#payment').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
</script>
```

Then I have my div containing the TnC's

```
            <div id="terms">
                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet, blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc. 
                </p>

                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet, blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc. 
                </p>
                <p>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis. Aenean elementum adipiscing lorem. Sed vitae volutpat ante. Aliquam pretium sem arcu, ac consequat enim blandit eget. Integer posuere arcu vulputate nisi interdum dignissim. Sed quis tortor risus. Vivamus leo lectus, ornare sed vehicula quis, hendrerit eu mi. Curabitur pulvinar luctus nibh, ut laoreet dolor venenatis et. Curabitur eu nulla congue, iaculis tellus sit amet, blandit lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus non augue eu cursus. Etiam neque neque, commodo id accumsan ac, auctor nec nunc. 
                </p>

            </div>
```

and finally the checkbox:

```
<input id="payment" type="checkbox" disabled name="terms"> <span class="redSmall">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam lacinia est non cursus rutrum. Donec vulputate tincidunt mollis.</span>
```

the checkbox is in form tags I was just saving time.

I cant see anything wrong here but when I scroll down the TnC's nothing happens

Ammended just to add the CSS here for the div element

```
#terms {      
  width: 780px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border:2px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: its already disabled, you want to enable it or disabled it

Comment: I need to enable it...sorry that was my mistake, ammended the question to fix that

Comment: Have you checked if the condition is met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a silly error.Use `.ready()` function.here is the code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
 $('#terms').scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() == $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height()) {
    $('#payment').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: brilliant! that works :) thankyou. I will accept as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#terms').scroll(function (e) {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            $('#payment').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfyNx/)**

Comment: Very nice answer Super, Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).prop({
  disabled: true
});
```

Is that you want to do ?

Comment: sorry my mistake I need to enable the checkbox...so disabled=false. but...this isnt working either. if it helps..i have just put an alert in my function and it doesnt do anything which means its not recognising that its scrolled down

Answer (score 0):

You just need yo use .removeAttr() function.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
   $("#payment").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Works on both x and y scrolls

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/PEX2d/1/)